# Mongoose find().populate()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

Hi everyone I am trying to return a populated array on the fields subCategories. When I use .findOne() or .findById() it works, but when I want to return many with .find(), because I am implementing filtering for a front-end end search it does not work.

Have a look.

```
export const findAllCategories = async (_, { search = null, page = 1, limit = 20 }, context) => {
  await jwtAuthentication.verifyTokenMiddleware(context);

  try {
    let searchQuery = {};

    if (search) {
      searchQuery = {
        $or: [{ name: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } }]
      };
    }

    const categories = await Category.find(searchQuery).popolate('subCategories')
      .limit(limit)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .lean();
    const count = await Category.countDocuments(searchQuery);

    return {
      categories,
      totalPages: Math.ceil(count / limit),
      currentPage: page
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return handleError(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: ya sas. what is `popolate`

Comment: that was not the error actually i fixed it, I was messing up the graphql type